# Android Espresso: How to create test-suite which may launch separate test classes with different activities?

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, android-espresso

I have just started studying Espresso tests, but I have searched throw StackOverFlow topics and couldn't found solution for my needs.

---

**Prehistory of my question:**

I have android application with lots of activities. Generally separate UI tests were created for different flows of the app (each flow require separate activity, so that's why I have implemented tests in a different classes).
In my case background and UI usync occurs, that's why I can't start from first activity and keep going to the next and next.
The only solution which I have found and it really work with current app - is using of idling resources for app activities.

**Question:**
SO now am trying to understand how can I put all these separate classes (each class use own rules and activities for these rules) to the functional suite??

---

**My experience:**

**1) Positive** - using idling resource which require changes in developer's source code, but there is still only one activity in suite:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class forSeveralActs {
    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<TargetedActivity> mTargetedActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TargetedActivity.class, true, true);`
        
    final String username = "test@mail.com";
    final String password = "12345678";
    private IdlingResource mIdlingRecourse;

    @Before
    public void setIdleResource() {
        mIdlingRecourse = mTargetedActivityRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingRecourse);
    }

    @Test
    public void PassPermission_and_goto_MainActivity() {
        // First activity - LoginActivity
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.activity_login_et_login))
                .perform(ViewActions.typeText(username));

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.activity_login_et_password))
                .perform(ViewActions.typeText(password))
                .perform(closeSoftKeyboard());

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.activity_login_btn_login))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .check(matches(isClickable()))
                .perform(ViewActions.click());

      // Here is elements of second activity - MainActivity, without idling methods I can't reach this element
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.helpMeCard_title))
                .check(matches(withText("help_me")));
    }

    @After
    public void unregisteredIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingRecourse != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingRecourse);
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example I have several tests and the last one will be performed on the next activity.

---

**2) Negative** - I have tried to launch all my tests (classes) though JUnit test-suite, so I just put all my classes (which also includes RULES for tests and ACTIVITIES) to the Junit suite (this scenario doesn't work at all):

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    {
            ESP_test1.class,
            ESP_test2.class,
            ESP_test3.class
    })

public class ESP_start {}
```

**Here is the same question which I posted above:**
How can I create suite from separate tests which are using different activities and rules, how it should look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case, maybe answer will be useful for someone else, this suite is correct, previously I have used parameters in my test-classes.
In this case app test-classes should be void without any params:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    {
            ESP_test1.class,
            ESP_test2.class,
            ESP_test3.class
    })

public class ESP_start {}
```

Comment: I have closed this issue, if anyone will have some related questions - you are free to ask.

Comment: I am very new to JUnit and Espresso and even with my TestSuite class setup the same way this code example shows, I was getting errors saying something about initialization and "Stub!" that I didn't understand.  I discovered my problem was that I was incorrectly trying to start/run my defined suite of tests from the TestRunner class instead of starting them from the TestSuite class (the empty body class.)  If you're reading this and having the same issue, try starting your tests from the TestSuite class.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use in kotlin as like this refer below cup of code.

```
@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    ESP_test1::class,
    ESP_test2::class,
    ESP_test3::class,
    ESP_test4::class
)
class TestSuite
```